# Creating a denormalized table from a normalized key-value table using 100s of joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, etl, olap

I have an ETL process which takes values from an input table which is a key value table with each row having a field ID and turning it into a more denormalized table where each row has all the values. Specifically, this is the input table:

```
StudentFieldValues (
    FieldId INT NOT NULL,
    StudentId INT NOT NULL,
    Day DATE NOT NULL,
    Value FLOAT NULL
)
```

`FieldId` is a foreign key from table `Field`, `Day` is a foreign key from table `Days`. The PK is the first 3 fields. There are currently 188 distinct fields. The output table is along the lines of:

```
StudentDays (
    StudentId INT NOT NULL,
    Day DATE NOT NULL,
    NumberOfClasses FLOAT NULL,
    MinutesLateToSchool FLOAT NULL,
    ... -- the rest of the 188 fields
)
```

The PK is the first 2 fields.

Currently the query that populates the output table does a self join with `StudentFieldValues` 188 times, one for each field. Each join equates `StudentId` and `Day` and takes a different `FieldId`. Specifically:

```
SELECT Students.StudentId, Days.Day, 
       StudentFieldValues1.Value NumberOfClasses, 
       StudentFieldValues2.Value MinutesLateToSchool,
       ...
INTO StudentDays
FROM Students
CROSS JOIN Days
LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentFieldValues StudentFieldValues1 
ON Students.StudentId=StudentFieldValues1.StudentId AND 
   Days.Day=StudentFieldValues1.Day AND
   AND StudentFieldValues1.FieldId=1
LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentFieldValues StudentFieldValues2 
ON Students.StudentId=StudentFieldValues2.StudentId AND 
   Days.Day=StudentFieldValues2.Day AND 
   StudentFieldValues2.FieldId=2
... -- 188 joins with StudentFieldValues table, one for each FieldId
```

I'm worried that this system isn't going to scale as more days, students and fields (especially fields) are added to the system. Already there are 188 joins and I keep reading that if you have a query with that number of joins you're doing something wrong. So I'm basically asking: Is this something that's gonna blow up in my face soon? Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do? It's important to note that this query is minimally logged and that's something that wouldn't have been possible if I was adding the fields one after the other.

More details:

- MS SQL Server 2014, 2x XEON E5 2690v2 (20 cores, 40 threads total), 128GB RAM. Windows 2008R2.
- 352 million rows in the input table, 18 million rows in the output table - both expected to increase over time.
- Query takes 20 minutes and I'm very happy with that, but performance degrades as I add more fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about doing this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT s.StudentId, d.Day, 
       max(case when sfv.FieldId = 1 then sfv.Value end) as NumberOfClasses, 
       max(case when sfv.FieldId = 2 then sfv.Value end) as MinutesLateToSchool,
       ...
INTO StudentDays
FROM Students s CROSS JOIN
     Days d LEFT OUTER JOIN
     StudentFieldValues sfv 
     ON s.StudentId = sfv.StudentId AND 
        d.Day = sfv.Day 
GROUP BY s.StudentId, d.Day;
```

This has the advantage of easy scalability.  You can add hundreds of fields and the processing time should be comparable (longer, but comparable) to fewer fields.  It is also easer to add new fields.

EDIT:

A faster version of this query would use subqueries instead of aggregation:

```
SELECT s.StudentId, d.Day, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 sfv.Value FROM StudentFieldValues WHERE sfv.FieldId = 1 and sfv.StudentId = s.StudentId and sfv.Day = sfv.Day) as NumberOfClasses, 
        (SELECT TOP 1 sfv.Value FROM StudentFieldValues WHERE sfv.FieldId = 2 and sfv.StudentId = s.StudentId and sfv.Day = sfv.Day) as MinutesLateToSchool,
       ...
INTO StudentDays
FROM Students s CROSS JOIN
     Days d;
```

For performance, you want a composite index on `StudentFieldValues(StudentId, day, FieldId, Value)`.

Comment: This looks very interesting, I will try this after I add an index on StudentFieldValues which accesses it using StudentId then Day then FieldId. Thanks!

Comment: This query took 9:54 to generate the output table vs 6:52 the original query took (described in the question). Just from looking at it, it can be that this query's performance scales better as the number of fields increases. The original table was cached in mem when I checked the performance of both queries.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is going to blow up. You have your definitions of "normalized" and "denormalized" backwards. The Field/Value table design is *not* a relational design. It's a variation of the [entity-attribute-value](/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) design, which has all sorts of problems.

I recommend you do not try to pivot the data in an SQL query. It doesn't scale well that way. Instea, you need to query it as a set of rows, as it is stored in the database, and fetch back the result set into your application. There you write code to read the data row by row, and apply the "fields" to fields of an object or a hashmap or something.

Comment: Are you saying not process the data into StudentDays that has 188 fields (+2 for PK) and instead use StudentFieldValues in my application? Queries on the actual data run much faster on StudentDays.

Comment: You could also fill the StudentDays table in multiple UPDATE queries, each with a more modest number of joins.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be some trial and error here to see what works but here are some things you can try:

- Disable indexes and re-enable after data load is complete
- Disable any triggers that don't need to be ran upon data load scenarios.

The above was taken from an [msdn post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/88ba469c-a9e1-4575-8df0-d57e9b3233db/ssislarge-table-denormalization) where someone was doing something similar to what you are.

- Think about trying to only update the de-normalized table based on changed records if this is possible.  Limiting the result set would be much more efficient if this is a possibility.
- You could try a more threaded iterative approach in code (C#, vb, etc) to build this table by student where you aren't doing the X number of joins all at one time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please note that the current query is INTO a new table - meaning: 1) the table doesn't exist before the query so there are no indexes or triggers to slow down the insert. 2) It's minimally logged which is a huge boost to performance that will be lost if anything is done iteratively.